# Why does using mapped types resolve to an union in this specific case?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I recently stumbled on the following TypeScript code:

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> =
    (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never
```

which converts unions like `string | number` to intersections `string & number`.

After extensive research, I thought I understood the underlying mechanics well and started tinkering with it in order to break it.

One of my tests was to build a function type which has specific overloads depending on a mapping like the following:

```
type Mapping = {
    one: {
        arg: true;
        ret: string;
    };
    two: {
        arg: string;
        ret: number;
    };
};

// Goal is to make this:
type Goal = ((arg: true) => string) & ((arg: string) => number);
```

In order to do so, I used mapped types to build the functions and relied on `UnionToIntersection` to combine them into overloads:

```
// Resolves to union of all values in record
type ValueOf<T extends Record<string, unknown>> = T[keyof T];

type BuildOverloadedFunction<
    T extends Record<
        string,
        {
            arg: unknown;
            ret: unknown;
        }
    >
    > = UnionToIntersection<ValueOf<
        {
            [P in keyof T]: (arg: T[P]["arg"]) => T[P]["ret"];
        }
    >>;

// Result
type Result = ((arg: true) => string) & ((arg: string) => number)
```

(`ValueOf` provided for completeness)

So far so good.

Things started to become strange when I thought

> Let's remove the first `extends` of `UnionToIntersection` so that the resolved type will be an intersection of the parameter types (`true & string` --> `never`)

Which gave the following code (renamed `NakedInfer` for clarity):

```
type NakedInfer<T> = T extends (k: infer I) => void ? I : never;
```

My surprise was that it resolved to `true | string`.

I then noticed that I used a naked `T` which would be distributed and performed the following change:

```
type ClothedInfer<T> = [T] extends [(k: infer I) => void] ? I : never;
```

Now `T` is properly "clothed" but the union remained.

After tinkering a bit more, I changed my `BuildOverloadedFunction` type to remove the mapped types and it suddenly resolved to `never` as I expected:

```
type Test2<
    T extends Record<
        string,
        {
            arg: unknown;
            ret: unknown;
        }
    >
    > = ClothedInfer<ValueOf<
        {
            one: (arg: true) => string;
            two: (arg: string) => number;
        }
    >>;
```

I now think I may miss some specific behavior related to mapped types and would like to know if it's the case or if I made a mistake.

Here is the whole code with some comments (And [here is the playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-dev.20201007#code/PTAECUFMGcHsBsBuNQBdagK4DsCWttRYAzUAQ3nlEQsxV0ICdIBjWRgEwFgAoVATwAOkUADVakAPLEAPABVQkAB6pI2DtAit2HGdFSMGAcwA0WbAGtssAO7YAfPdABeUHIDaFyPxJuAugDcvLwgoAAiuPqGAEaYqhxoABZklprooByRBrixqLjIoGzquHkEFGhCKAC0VU7WoAyqjNCspdi8AsKgAHJkXhwAktjEkIzyTq4KyqrqmgAUFgBcDcOjoAMAlC5OiLC4CQD866DL2JDIjEE8IWDdsKgZWTFxkAnRrGSYLYXw94mvoBqTgAqngCCtCgQDGQqjRDCkHoJYNASvhCECVk0Wiw2h1KqAAMK-VD-QarMZyCagdxyPyKFRqDTUhbLBgjRjrLbOHZ7Dh0o4DE6gM4XK43UAAUSUghSHABbNGADotHAkCh0iK1nMDHRQAAyUBRYwbPFdADKqkEAEYXGIJNIZABvXigV1EM7LOZkRhGZY6yBcpxG7BGK5utA2WCe72+w3ZEOB4WYAC270uvAAvk5poz5ksVuzOdtqLzQAKhZr09ceKEIkbcq9lVBVcg0hgcGjQNrGLqAD5xwwJ00iC2QQQAJltvX6Q3ZMnE8DoDudPHDBEg0Z9fp7AeLwdDLrdqEjm9j+8T2BTaauWfsYprt3uj3rLw4TZgCFbaAwla7-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-ncSGd6gKE+6gP2-rR6wcfMJC2BJ+zKf6Bz6fGFnoSVrwQA)):

```
// Resolves to union of all values in record
type ValueOf<T extends Record<string, unknown>> = T[keyof T];

// Distributed thanks to distributive conditional types --> no intersection
type NakedInfer<T> = T extends (k: infer I) => void ? I : never;

// Not distributed because clothed --> Union in contra-variant position --> intersection
type ClothedInfer<T> = [T] extends [(k: infer I) => void] ? I : never;

// Expanded infer. Resolves to never (true & string)
type Step1 = ValueOf<{
    one: (arg: true) => string;
    two: (arg: string) => number;
}> extends (k: infer I) => void ? I : never;

// Distributed. Resolves to union (true | string)
type Step2 = NakedInfer<ValueOf<{
    one: (arg: true) => string;
    two: (arg: string) => number;
}>>;

// Not distributed. Resolves to never (true & string)
type Step3 = ClothedInfer<ValueOf<{
    one: (arg: true) => string;
    two: (arg: string) => number;
}>>;

// More complex example
type Mapping = {
    one: {
        arg: true;
        ret: string;
    };
    two: {
        arg: string;
        ret: number;
    };
};

// Builds functions based on the provided Mapping using mapped types.
// Expands to exactly the same thing used above and below.
// Unexpectedly resolves to union
type Test1<
    T extends Record<
        string,
        {
            arg: unknown;
            ret: unknown;
        }
    >
    > = ClothedInfer<ValueOf<
        {
            [P in keyof T]: (arg: T[P]["arg"]) => T[P]["ret"];
        }
    >>;

// Same as Test1 but the mapped types and function building is omitted.
// Properly resolves to never
type Test2<
    T extends Record<
        string,
        {
            arg: unknown;
            ret: unknown;
        }
    >
    > = ClothedInfer<ValueOf<
        {
            one: (arg: true) => string;
            two: (arg: string) => number;
        }
    >>;

// Both t1 and t2 should resolve to never
declare const t1: Test1<Mapping>; // string | true
declare const t2: Test2<Mapping>; // never
```

Comment: I'd say this is an instance of [microsoft/TypeScript#30020](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30020) and/or [microsoft/TS#30708](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30708) where the compiler eagerly evaluates `Test1` and takes the wrong path.  It's not fun and I don't have a great solution.  The workaround is to write `Test1` as `{ [P in keyof T]: (arg: T[P]["arg"]) => T[P]["ret"]; }[keyof T] extends (k: infer I) => void ? I : never;` directly, since composing non-distributive conditionals doesn't work right.  I could write this up as an answer when I get a chance.

Comment: It indeed seems to be my issue, thank you. In the issue it looks like it's a feature but it really seems like a bug to me.